# Spring security User Principal keeps coming back as anonymousUser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on this override below and even though I login with proper credentials I keep getting 403 or 500 errors.  My filter ordering is correct as it is the same as our other apps so I guess I am wrong in the anyRequest() part that I am missing something.  How do I get my credentials to persist?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("read_only", "read_write", "read_write_delete")
            .and()
            .addFilter(securityContextPersistenceFilter())
            .addFilterAfter(preAuthFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(ssoFilter(), PreAuthFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(new RequestContextFilter(), SSOFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(new CrossFramePreventionFilter(), RequestContextFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(characterEncodingFilter, CrossFramePreventionFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(exceptionTranslationFilter(), CharacterEncodingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(new NoCacheFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: Follow up: this lets me into the main page which doesnt require any role or auth.  However, the main page calls many other methods which have '@PreAuthorize' and those return 500 access denied.  The securityContextPersistanceFilter does not seem to be persisting any authentication details as every user comes back as anonymousUser with Role_Anonymous which then fails the '@preauthorize' check.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failure is because order matters in the filter chain and I had the preAuthFilter listed before the ssoFilter.  The ssoFilter sets and removes UserPrincipal.authenticatedUser which the preAuth filter uses to create an authentication token.  Since I had preAuthFilter first the authenticated user was null and therefore token creation failed.  Working its way through the filter chain if there still is no token created then spring automatically adds an AnonymousAuthenticationFilter which creates an AnonymousAuthenticationToken with "anonymousUser" and "ROLE_ANONYMOUS" like i saw in logs.

Reversing the order of those filters allowed for a valid PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken to be created and then everything worked as expected.